# Word for "they couldn't do it even if they wanted to"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I were to say something like:

- "They couldn't have done X."
- "They're incapable of having done X."
- "It's not possible that they did X."

It can be interpreted in one of two ways:

1. They're morally/psychologically incapable of doing X (like I'm physically capable of murdering someone, but I'd never be able to bring myself to do so).
2. It's physically/logistically/biologically impossible for them to have done X (like it's impossible for the government to fake the existence of the Moon).

Is there any single word which will convey meaning #2, so I won't have to use some wordy phrasing like "they couldn't do it even if they wanted to"?

Comment: Strictly-speaking, *impossible* covers #2 while *unthinkable* covers #1. Unfortunately, *impossible* has now expanded to cover #1 as well.

Comment: I'd call it a "sentence".  Your #2 definition does not properly describe the sentence as it does not capture the "unwilling" aspect.

Comment: I think you'd get closest by using *wouldn't* instead of *couldn't*.

Answer (score -2):

**Physically** [*impaired*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/impaired)

> 1. Weakened or damaged.

**Psychologically** [*incapacitated*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/incapacitate)

> 1. Prevent from functioning in a normal way.

*Impaired* and *incapacitated* can generally be used interchangeably too.

**Logistically** [*impractical*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impractical)

> 2. North American: Impossible to do; impracticable.

Also, [not] [*feasible*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/feasible)

> Possible and practical to do easily or conveniently.

**Morally** [*bound*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bound) {to do [or not do] something}

> bound<sup>3</sup>:
>
> 1.1. Obliged by law, circumstances, or duty to do something.

Source used: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/)